# Fetch HTTP Post Vue Data in Laravel API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm having a really tough time fetching HTTP Post data sent from Vue, in my Laravel API.

What I have is extremely simple.

```html
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/api/vue-data',
    data: { firstName: "Dally" },
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
})
```

And then the function in my Laravel controller is this...

```html
public function vueData(Request $request)
{
    return $request->firstName;
}
```

The data is being sent as I can see it in Chrome Dev tools but why can't I fetch it in Laravel?

I've tried vue-resource as opposed to Axios but still no luck.

**UPDATE #1**

So when I use Axios I get the following error.

[image]

And when I use vue-resource I get this.

[image]

Data is passing...

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

If I change the Laravel controller code to this, I get a response in VueJS. Seems like the controller function in Laravel isn't receiving the Vue data or that I'm accessing it wrong.

```html
public function vueData(Request $request)
{
    return "Testing";
}
```

Comment: What about debugging on `$request->all()` then figure out if there's data keyed `firstName` there?

Comment: `but why can't I fetch it in Laravel?`  Well, what's happening?  Do you get an error?

Comment: You need to send FormData object since you are setting `'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Have updated my original post guys.

Comment: what does the 500 errors says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Was such a noob mistake it's embarrassing. I was missing the following in my controller.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you POST'ing to Laravel you need to specify CSRF token in request.

Add to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And set default `X-CSRF-TOKEN` for axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
```

Comment: You only need to do that if your using web.php for routing mate. I'm using api.php so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you POST to Laravel you need to specify CSRF token in request.

Add to your :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

First you should add following line in app.js

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf- 
token"]').getAttribute('content')
};

const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };  
 axios.post('/admin/theme/',{name: "yourname"},config).then(response=>{
 if(response.data.success === true){

 }).catch((error) => {

 });
```

i hope it's help for you.

Comment: You only need to do that if your using web.php for routing mate. I'm using api.php so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As i can't see what error are you getting, my best guest is this

The errors is because you're trying to get the data like this `return $request->firstName;`, but in the image you shown you're sending

```
{
    params : {
        firstName : 'Dally'
    }
}
```

Try getting `params` first then returning what you want like

```
public function vueData(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input('params');
    return $data->firstName;
    //if this fails, maybe params contains a array so do
    //return $data['firstName'];
}
```